# single variable polynomials root boundary?

Tags: polynomials, roots

What's the root boundary of $ c_1 x^n + c_2 x^{n-1} + ... + c_nx + c_{n+1} = 0 $?
A boundary give in Sipser's "Introduction to the Theory of Computation", problem 3.21:

> $ |x_0| <(n+1) \frac{c_{max}}{|c_1|}$ where $c_{max}$ is largest absolute value of $c_i$

While I think a better boundary could be: $|x_0| <= 2 |\frac{c_{max}}{c_1}|$.
Proof:
$ x > 2 |\frac{c_{max}}{c_1}| \Rightarrow $
$|c_1 x^n| > 2 |c_2 x^{n-1}|$,
$|c_1 x^n| > 4 |c_3 x^{n-2}|$,
...
i.e. $|c_1 x^n| > 2^{i-1} |c_i x^{n-(i-1)}|$
$ \Rightarrow |c_1 x^n| > |c_2 x^{n-1}| + ... + |c_nx| + |c_{n+1}| > |c_2 x^{n-1} + ... + c_nx + c_{n+1}| $
$ \Rightarrow c_1 x^n + c_2 x^{n-1} + ... + c_nx + c_{n+1} \neq 0$

Above boundary & proof is correct?

Comment: Why is $|c_1x^n|>4|c_3x^{n-2}|$? If you square the defining inequality you get $|c_1^2x^2|>|4c_3^2|$ which is not the above

Comment: @dxiv root of your example is 1, $ c_{max} = 3, c_1 = 3 $, which satisfy: $1 < 2 |\frac{3}{3}| $

Comment: @Conrad $ |c_1x^n| > 4|c_3x^{n-2}| $ as: $ \frac{|c_1x^n|}{|c_3x^{n-2}|} = |\frac{c_1}{c_3} x^2| > |\frac{c_1}{c_3} (2|\frac{c_{max}}{c_1}|)^2 | = |4 (\frac{c_{max}}{c_3})(\frac{c_{max}}{c_1})| >= |4 * 1 * 1| $

Comment: Yes you are right but actually  the better bound is $1+q$ where $q=\max_{2, ..,n+1}|c_k|/|c_1|$ (similar proof) as this one beats the bound above unless $q=1$ when it equals it (more generally one can optimize $a(1+\max_{2,..,n+1}\frac{a^{1-k}|c_k|}{|c_1|})$ on $a>0$ and the above is for $a=1$; these all come from the Cauchy bound which is of course the best bound possible in terms of the coefficients

Comment: @ShaqXu Right, comment removed. I thought $\,c_{max}=\max_{\,\color{red}{k \ge 2}\,} |c_k|\,$, but apparently that's $\,k \ge \color{red}{1}\,$.

Comment: @Conrad , yes the approach is base on series convergence. Sure with 1 + q there is a better convergent series, which is a step forward on the boundary. Thanks.